# Russian equivalents of the English idiom "So much for (a peaceful vacation)!"

Tags: одним-словом, idioms

> First ..., and now this!? **So much for** a peaceful vacation!

In English, you use the expression "so much for X" ironically and dejectedly when something didn't turn out the way you'd hoped. In this specific example, something put a damper on what was supposed to be a peaceful vacation. I wonder if the following two phrases sound idiomatic enough?

> First ..., and now this!? **Не слишком ли это для** "мирного отпуска"?
>
> First ..., and now this!? **Это уж слишком для** "мирного отпуска".

Comment: Phrase #1 expresses hesitation about "peacefulness" of the vacation, phrase #2 is more assertive about it, but none captures the feeling of regret which the original English phrase implies.

Answer (score 12):

Yes they do.

But the Russian phrase would be more accurately back rendered in English as **too much for** rather than **so much for**

While **so much for** can be translated as

> Вот такой (вот) "мирный отпуск"
>
> Вот тебе и "мирный отпуск"
>
> Про "мирный отпуск" можно забыть
>
> Коту под хвост весь "мирный отпуск"

[... and with many more other options](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=so+much+for&l1=1)

Comment: Hi. Do you detect nuances between my two phrases?

Comment: As a side note "мирный отпуск" sounds to me not quite idiomatic. Not sure how to substitute though. "Тихий?" "Спокойный?" In Russian "мирный  отпуск" sounds to mean that there were no war or quarrel whereas English version indicate that it was spent "in peace" ("в покое"), which is slightly different.

Comment: Another option for *so much for* – *хорошенький (-ая etc.)*, as in "Хорошенький мирный отпуск!"

Comment: @Alone-zee i do between the English and the Russian but not between the two Russian versions

Comment: @Andriy M to me **мирный** sounds legit in this context, not a shade of jarring, **спокойный** of course fits as well, or **безмятежный**

Answer (score 2):

Тоже мне мирный отпуск - (тоже мне _______ (нашёлся)) - used to express indignation and dissatisfaction with something.

И это мирным отпуском называется?! (A little more emphatic than some of the examples offered above)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a proverb

> Вот тебе, бабушка, и Юрьев день.

It could be used in any situation, when you are disappointed with an unexpected incident.