# What does "тоже мне" mean?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выражения

What is the best way to translate these?

- Тоже мне!
- Тоже мне герой.
- Тоже мне новость.

-

Comment: related  - https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/russian-equivalents-of-the-english-idiom-so-much-for-a-peaceful-vacation/15941#15941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an expression that conveys not being impressed in the least. You're just saying that you're completely unimpressed by something or someone.

*"So what?" "And?" "Big deal!"* (with a really unimpressed intonation).

It basically says what in English is normally conveyed by simply saying "meh..."

*"Some hero...", "Real hero here!", "Wow, what a man."* (all very sarcastic).

*"What a surprise!", "No way, really?"* (sarcastically). Or simply *"That's old news".*

Answer (score 0):

- It's not rocket science! Tough work, my ass!
- Way to be a hero! A fat lot of heroism you are!
- Now there’s a surprise! You're about a century late! The Dutch have taken Holland!