# Please explain the phrase "Тоже мне новость!"

Tags: перевод, выражения

I saw this example sentence on [LearnRussianWords.com](https://learnrussianwords.com/search-results/?find=not%20news):

> То́же мне но́вость! Об э́том бы́ло изве́стно уже́ неде́лю наза́д.

The suggested translation was:

> That's not news! It was known a week ago.

However I could not understand the phrase: `То́же мне но́вость`. Literally it sounds like the opposite: "That's also news to me". Why is it translated as: "That's not news!"?

Comment: Related: [What does “тоже мне” mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/21053/9256)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

«Тоже мне», with words exactly in this sequence, is a set phrase that means "not really", "as if" and is used to express irony.

If you wanted to say "this is news to me too", that would be «**Для меня** это тоже новость».

Answer (score 6):

Consider this translation:

> as if that's news

Comment: I see. Do you have some other examples of how to use the word "Тоже" to mean "as if"? I always thought of it as "also".

Comment: @I.Hasanov Only тоже мне has that meaning as an idiom, greater than the sum of its parts.

Comment: Similar question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/what-does-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-mean